# Print a single value in parallel array

Tags: java

Does anyone know how I can output the single corresponding value in a parallel array? Say this is a pair `(a | 1, b | 2, c | 3, etc., etc.)`. If the user enters a then 1 would print.

Comment: So just do `System.out.println(userInput+" | "+(userInput-96))` With `userInput` being a `char` (this will work only in the case of lowercase characters.

Comment: Why not use a `Map`?

Answer (score 1):

Do a traditional indexed linear search, then use the index to get the second value.

#### Example:

```
for(int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++){
    if (array1[i].equals(SEARCH_TERM_HERE)){
        return array2[i]; // Or print, etc.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you search 'a' retrieve the index of 'a' from array1 and print it

```
 for (int index  = 0; index  < array1 .length; index ++) {
    if (array1[i].equals("a")){
    System.out.println(array2[index]);
     break;
}
}
```